# Can anyone explain this analog clock code

Tags: javascript, canvas, clock

I got understand everything except how they draw clock numbers. Please explain `drawNumbers()` function. This example is from w3schools.com, they didn't explained these things.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"
                style="background-color:#333">
            </canvas>
            <script>
                var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                var radius = canvas.height / 2;
                ctx.translate(radius, radius);
                radius = radius * 0.90
                drawClock();
                
                function drawClock() {
                  drawFace(ctx, radius);
                  drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
                }
                
                function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {
                  var ang;
                  var num;
                  ctx.font = radius*0.15 + "px arial";
                  ctx.textBaseline="middle";
                  ctx.textAlign="center";
                  for(num = 1; num < 13; num++){
                    // please explain from here
                    ang = num * Math.PI / 6;
                    ctx.rotate(ang);
                    ctx.translate(0, -radius*0.85);
                    ctx.rotate(-ang);
                    ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
                    ctx.rotate(ang);
                    ctx.translate(0, radius*0.85);
                    ctx.rotate(-ang);
                  }
                }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What is the implementation of `drawFace`?

Comment: This is basic geometry for calculating the radius of a circle, except that with the `canvas`, instead of degrees, it's measured in radians.

Comment: This example is from w3schools.com .... Problem solved then.

Answer (score 0):

I good approach to understand the code could be to add texts between the different executed movements (as showed below). If you draw them all it isn't legible, but you can comment/un-comment one by one and see where the current position is in each step.

Edit: I also added comments with what I understood.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = canvas.height / 2;
ctx.translate(radius, radius);
radius = radius * 0.90
drawClock();

function drawClock() {
  drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
}

function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {
  var ang;
  var num;
  ctx.font = radius * 0.15 + "px arial";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  for (num = 1; num < 13; num++) {
                               // we start at the center, looking at 12
    ang = num * Math.PI / 6;          // angle from 12 to number in radians
    ctx.fillText("a", 0, 0);
    ctx.rotate(ang);                  // look at the number
    ctx.fillText("b", 0, 0);
    ctx.translate(0, -radius * 0.85); // move to the number
    ctx.fillText("c", 0, 0);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);                 // look to 12 to write the number
                                      // in right position
    ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
    ctx.rotate(ang);                  // look away from center
    ctx.fillText("d", 0, 0);
    ctx.translate(0, radius * 0.85);  // move to center
    ctx.fillText("e", 0, 0);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);                 // look to 12
    ctx.fillText("f", 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" style="background-color:#333">
        </canvas>
```

### Doc

[CanvasRenderingContext2D.translate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate)

[CanvasRenderingContext2D.rotate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rotate)

Comment: There is no need to provide Fiddle's to show executable code. That's why we have "code snippets", right here in your answers.

Comment: It's easier for me to edit in fiddle than here (you need to copy to answer to edit and you cannot save it). Why not have both? I ask because maybe is there some rule against I am not aware.

Comment: And thanks for adding the code snippet. I think it's good to have both options.

Comment: You do not need to copy the answer to edit. You just hit the "edit" link and then the "edit code snippet" link. In general, it is not encouraged to post parts of an answer to 3rd party links because those links can die over time. Since a "code snippet" gives you the same functionality of a Fiddle, but right here, that is what is encouraged.

Comment: Still lacking the option to save modified versions without posting new answer (as far as I know) but I understand the avoid-dead-links argument. Thanks for the explanation. I move the [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/cCrul/810bu8kd/) here to keep the answer cleaner.

Comment: I don't think you understand. There is generally no need to save multiple versions, but if you did want to have a second version of your code you can just go into edit mode on your answer and copy from `<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->` to `<!-- end snippet -->` and then paste at the bottom of your question to create a second code snippet that is identical to the first. Then you can just edit the second one as you need to.